# Ng-include doesn't work

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs

I have simple `angular.js` application. Also i have `index.html` as a front page of my web application, now i want to create `footer.html` and include it with `ng-include` directive to my `index.html`.

I have root controller:

```
function RootController ($scope) {
    $scope.templates = [{name : 'footer.html', url : 'views/footer.html'}];

    $scope.getFooter = function(){
        return $scope.templates[0];
    }
}
```

And my `index.html` template:

```
<div ng-controller="RootController" ng-include="getFoooter()">
  ....
</div>
```

`footer.html` has a simple html: `<div>Test Test Test</div>`

But when i open `index.html` i don't see footer. Why? How can include it correctly?

**UPD**

Problem solved. Maybe someone be useful my solution:

It works with:

```
<div ng-controller="SkinController" data-ng-include data-src="getFooter()">

</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: hard to answer if you post half of the code required to understand your problem.

Comment: you have to use src property with ng-include but this is missing

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
ng-include="getFooter().url"
```

or

```
return $scope.templates[0].url;
```